# Controlling animation speed by duration of keydown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling

Pl. check this http://jsfiddle.net/sKeNP/

I am trying to make a simple horizontal slider with following properties:

1. It should show 3 elements at a time.
2. It should have keyboard navigation.
3. The dots corresponding to current three slides should be BIG
4. While sliding, the slides should move 1 at a time, rather than 3 at a time
5. It should move multiple slides if the right or left key is pressed for long duration.

I've been able to achieve all this.

Only problem is that when left or right key is pressed down for long time, the sliding animation is not smooth/fast enough. Can anybody help me dynamically change animation speed for long duration keydown. Similarly, the animation speed should fasten for multiple (lets say 5 or 6) keydown events (for left and right keys) in quick succession.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to simply increase the animation speed every time you receive a keydown message and reset it whenever you get a keyup. See my amendment here: http://jsfiddle.net/sKeNP/1/.

You are having another potential problem however, in that your numbers and scrollbar aren't in sync. When the user scrolls to the end of the scroll bar using the arrow keys, the animation in still happening. Perhaps this is by design however.

Comment: Thanks Godwin.. your solution works partly.. but the animation is still not what I wanted.. as you have pointed out the animation is not in sync with the scrollbar.. that might be a part of the problem 

What I want is apple-like smooth horizontal sliding which:

1. Gains speed based on how quickly user is swiping multiple times in quick succession :: clicking the '>' & '<' or pressing cursor keys multiple times in quick succession.

2. Takes care of alternating directions of animations synchronously.

I am extremely new to jQ (started 3 days back), and hence require help.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with apple products but it sounds to me like what you want to do is to basically have a div with a scrollbar but have your own custom scrollbar instead. It that's the case, it probably makes more sense to use something that has already been made and tested like one of these: http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/. You'll be able to style any part of the scrollbar as you like.